# Add string between two patterns - sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm looking to build a startup script that will add a string of text between two patterns.

```
8.34.217.13 cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com
10.128.0.2 instance-1.c.testenvio1.internal instance-1 **want to add string here** # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

I want it to look like this:

```
8.34.217.13 cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com
10.128.0.2 instance-1.c.testenvio1.internal instance-1 104.197.247.254 instance1.com  # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

I'm using the following sed command but it inserts my string when it encounters the first "instance-1"

```
sed -i 's/\<instance-1\>/& 104.197.247.254 instance1.com/' /etc/hosts


8.34.217.13 cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com
10.128.0.2 instance-1 104.197.247.254 instance1.com.c.testenvio1.internal instance-1  # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

Comment: Include the space after instance1 into the pattern.

Comment: is it simply: sed -i 's/\<instance-1 \>/& 104.197.247.254 instance1.com/' /etc/hosts. This did not make any changes

Comment: your `\>` matches the end of word, which would not happen if you include the space in your pattern.   You want `sed -i 's/\<instance-1 /& 104.197.247.254 instance1.com /' /etc/hosts`

Comment: Of course that wouldn't work if the second field ended with the literal `instance-1`, as it would still replace that instance

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Good note. `\<instance-1\>` would match anything like `_instance-1_` , `instance-1.stuff` & `-instance-1-` and so. Perhaps the op should go for something like `/([[:blank:]]+instance-1[[:blank:]]+)(#.*)$/\1 104.197.247.254 instance1.com \2/` perhaps with the `-E` option of the `sed` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some insight about where the data is coming from is certainly helpful here.

The `# Added by Google` suggests that those lines contain information about Google Compute Engine instances. More importantly, they are lines added by Google and fortunately follows a predefined pattern.

In that case, something like below would help

```
$ sed -Ei -- 's/([[:blank:]]+instance-1[[:blank:]]+)(#.*)$/\1 104.197.247.254 instance1.com \2/' /etc/hosts
```

**Output**

```
8.34.217.13 cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com
10.128.0.2-instance-1-c.testenvio1.internal instance-1   104.197.247.254 instance1.com # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

---

<sup>**Sidenote:** The actual number of spaces are preserved too.</sup>

Comment: Google uses a network daemon to update /etc/hosts upon reboot. Upon reboot /etc/hosts gets updated with the default config. # Added by Google stays consistent. Your expression works but does not commit the changes to /etc/hosts. I tried changing -E to -i (in-place edit) but ran into this error: "sed: -e expression #1, char 81: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS"

Comment: @glux you should put the both that is `-Ei` The `E` enables extended regex and the `i` does the in-place edit. Since the `i` looks for an argument for a backup prefix, it is required that it is put last.. You can even add a `--` to mark the end of the arguments..See the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/^\([0-9.]* [^ ]* \<instance-1\>\)/\1 104.197.247.254 instance1.com/' /etc/hosts
```

This expression will read the first two fields, and then try to match `instance-1` in the third field only (this assumes that the fields are seperated by a single space delimiter -- you can adjust the regex if that's not the case...)

The `\(` and `\)` indicate that sed should store the matched text in variable `\1`.  The `^` forces it to only match from the beginning of the line.   The rest is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Include the whitespace after `instance-1` which distinguishes it from the first occurrence:

```
$ sed -i 's/instance-1 /&104.197.247.254 instance1.com /g' inputFile
```

OR

if you know it is always the second occurrence, then use, `/2` to replace it,

```
$ sed -i 's/instance-1/& 104.197.247.254 instance1.com /2' inputFile
```

For future reference, if you want to add a string between two patterns

```
$ sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/s//& INSERT THIS TEXT/g' inputFile
```

For this example, it would look like,

```
# You still need that whitespace to distinguish the second occurrence from first:
$ sed '/instance-1 /,/# Added/s//&104.197.247.254 instance1.com /g' inputFile
```

Comment: This would match stuff like `some-stuff-followed-byinstance1(space)` and doing an inplace edit with `-i` may result in undesired changes

Comment: pattern matching is based on input `pattern`. If `pattern` changes, then result will also change. In any case, one can safely use the second option provided the assumption made is true.